# What happened to "OR" search for tags?

Tags: support, search

Until yesterday I used to search for unanswered questions with an "OR" search for some tags covering my expertise. Let's say

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/linq+or+entity-framework?tab=newest

This is what shows at the right:

> [image]

Since today any "OR" search seems to result in `0` results. Is this a deliberate change in the search engine? I can't find anything about it in [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Maybe I should add that I specifically search this way to try and answer users that are currently waiting for answers. Searching with one specific tag does not show all candidate questions. This “OR” search in new questions is perfect for my purpose.

Comment: I'm a lookin'. When did it last work? I deployed a change a few hours ago that could be related. But it depends: when did you last see it work?

Comment: As a short term thing wile I investigate: use `%20` instead of `+`: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/linq%20or%20entity-framework?tab=newest

Comment: @Felix `or` has worked for *years*

Comment: I'm revoking the "close" votes (relating to the new search engine): this has got nothing *whatsoever* to do with search. That path doesn't even *use* search.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks. I saw it last work yesterday, 22-01-2013, maybe 10 PM(GMT).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fixed and deployed; peripherally related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164696/cant-see-unanswered-c-questions), but now fixed in a way that should work equally for both scenarios.

Comment: Marc, you're a miracle! Thanks.

Comment: @Gert a miracle? dammit - now I have a pressing desire to debunk myself...