# Filter questions on Stack Overflow [tag] OR [tag]

Tags: support, tags, search

Is it possible to define a filter on Stack Overflow to see only the newest questions for a set of tags? Now I have three different app-tabs in Firefox and one tab for a specific tag.

For example, one Stack Overflow page opened which displays the newest questions that are tagged with:

```
[C#] OR [[C#] and [TDD]] OR [entity-framework]
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164714/what-happened-to-or-search-for-tags).

Comment: Search for `[tag1] [or] [tag2]`